# why this code in Action Script 3 not working when i publish it in html

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash

why this code in Action Script 3  not working when i publish it in html

its worke when i test it in flash program put when i publish it in html not working
some function not working

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;

// The player SWF file on www.youtube.com needs to communicate with your host
// SWF file. Your code must call Security.allowDomain() to allow this
// communication.
Security.allowDomain("www.youtube.com");

// This will hold the API player instance once it is initialized.
var player:Object;

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoaderInit);
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3"));

function onLoaderInit(event:Event):void {
    addChild(loader);
    loader.content.addEventListener("onReady", onPlayerReady);
}

function autoClick():void
{
    //=========================
    //Some nested children, we need to dig through a bit to get to the LargePlayButton
    var safeLoader:DisplayObjectContainer = (loader.content as DisplayObjectContainer).getChildAt(0) as DisplayObjectContainer;
    var videoApplication:DisplayObjectContainer = safeLoader.getChildAt(0) as DisplayObjectContainer;
    var largePlayBtn:DisplayObjectContainer = videoApplication.getChildAt(6) as DisplayObjectContainer; 
    //=========================
    //And finally dispatching our event to this button. It will think that a person has clicked it
    largePlayBtn.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK, 
                                       true, 
                                       true, 
                                       stage.stageWidth / 2,
                                       stage.stageHeight / 2));

}

function onPlayerReady(event:Event):void {
    // Event.data contains the event parameter, which is the Player API ID 
    trace("player ready:", Object(event).data);

    // Once this event has been dispatched by the player, we can use
    // cueVideoById, loadVideoById, cueVideoByUrl and loadVideoByUrl
    // to load a particular YouTube video.
    player = loader.content;
    // Set appropriate player dimensions for your application
    player.setSize(300, 250);

    player.cueVideoById("zlOB8nPdPG8",0);
    //====================================================
    //As long as player is loaded we can call our function
    autoClick();
}
```

pleas help me to solve this problem fast

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, and HTML does work.
Just that it won't work if you double click to open it, it need to open it in a webserver. Do you have Apache / MAMP / XAMMP / Appserv installed on your machine?

Comment: i need autoplay working like i test in flash program